# Mysql Check whether customer bought monthly

Tags: mysql

this is a sample of my table. (Actual table contains much more rows)

```
--------------------------------------------------
fInvoice | fDebtorcode | fCompanyname | fdate
123      | A001        | ABC Company  | 2017-02-01
234      | A002        | CDE Company  | 2017-03-02
345      | A003        | FGH Company  | 2017-03-05
456      | A001        | ABC Company  | 2017-04-02
567      | A001        | ABC Company  | 2017-04-04
678      | A002        | CDE Company  | 2017-04-04
```

I'd like to find out how many companies bought from us monthly. here's what I have so far:

```
select 
fdebtorcode As Debtorcode, 
fcompanyname As CompanyName, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM  invoicetable WHERE fdate > '2017-03-31' and fdate < '2017-05-01' and fdebtorcode = Debtorcode) As April,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM  invoicetable WHERE fdate > '2017-02-28' and fdate < '2017-04-01' and fdebtorcode = Debtorcode) As March,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM  invoicetable WHERE fdate > '2017-01-31' and fdate < '2017-03-01' and fdebtorcode = Debtorcode) As February
from tinvoicehistory 
where fdivision = 'Stationary'
group by fdebtorcode 
order by fdebtorcode
```

Now, I've got 2 more requirements:

1. a column called "Purchased Monthly" which gives me a "yes" for companies which bought monthly, or a "no" if not.
2. to only show companies who bought at least once in these 3 months. (my current result shows all of them including those that have already shut down)

Do let me know if there's a better way of going about it. All help appreciated. Thanks

Comment: does what you have work so far? Whats the problem you have?

Comment: what you consider as "monthly"? If for a company there is at least a single row for each month?

Comment: what I have currently works, but I need to have the other 2 requirements as well.

Comment: as long as there's a row each month.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following solution.  I wrap your original query, slightly modified, and then use the monthly totals to create the two columns you want.  If a company purchased in all three months, then it shows `yes` in the monthly purchase column.  If a company made a purchase in at least one month, then it shows `yes` in the any purchase column.

I also removed your subqueries, and replaced them with `CASE` expressions using conditional aggregation.  Also, I used the `MONTH()` function instead of checking the date ranges as you had originally, which is clumsy and even a bit error prone.  It can be error prone because it is easy to botch an endpoint of a month, and also February doesn't always have 28 every year (it can have 29 in a leap year).

```
SELECT t.*,
       CASE WHEN t.February > 0 AND t.March > 0 AND t.April > 0
            THEN 'yes' ELSE 'no' END AS purchased_monthly,
       CASE WHEN t.February > 0 OR t.March > 0 OR t.April > 0
            THEN 'yes' ELSE 'no' END AS purchased_once
FROM
(
    SELECT
        fdebtorcode AS Debtorcode, 
        fcompanyname AS CompanyName,   -- non aggregate column; this may be bad
        SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(fdate) = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS February,
        SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(fdate) = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS March,
        SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(fdate) = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS April
    FROM tinvoicehistory 
    WHERE fdivision = 'Stationary'
    GROUP BY fdebtorcode 
) t
ORDER BY t.fdebtorcode
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have a look at mysql's MONTH() and YEAR() functions.
Then you can try something like:

```
SELECT fdebtorcode As Debtorcode, fcompanyname As CompanyName,COUNT(*) AS purchases
FROM tinvoicehistory 
WHERE fdivision = 'Stationary'
GROUP BY YEAR(fdate), MONTH(fdate) DESC, fdebtorcode 
ORDER BY fdebtorcode
```

to start with.